# Flex - Can you use the FileReference.upload() function to upload files to Sharepoint or do I have to use the SP web services?

Tags: apache-flex, sharepoint, upload, filereference

Can you use the FileReference.upload() function to upload files to Sharepoint or do I have to use the SP web services? This is without adding your own ASP.NET Web Services, just using the built in SP Web Services.

Thanks again,
Mauricio

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the Sharepoint Webservices to do that. If FileReference.Upload works, I would be very surprised.